# Define Max and Min values in a multiple Excel data range

Tags: excel, range, max, min

I have a bunch of data, about ~2500 values, which contain undefined ranges.  The data can be sorted numerically, there are no repeating values, and the ranges can be defined manually.  Because I have so much data, I am hoping there is an Excel function that can help me define and group the ranges.  I then need to determine the Max and Min values of these ranges.  Can anyone help?  Below is a column of the type of data I need to sort:

```
Data:
26
27
28
29
39
40
61
135
136
137
138
241
242
1213
1221
1222
1223
1224
1225
1226
1228
1229
1230
3133
3134
3606
4060
4061
4062
4063
4064
4065
4066
4067
4068
4069
4070
4071
```

You can see the ranges are:

```
Range 1 = 26:40, 
Range 2 = 61:61, 
Range 3 = 135:138, 
Range 4 = 241:242, 
Range 5 = 1213:1213, 
Range 6 = 1221:1226, 
Range 7 = 1228:1230, 
Range 8 = 3133:3134, 
Range 9 = 3606:3606, 
Range 10 = 4060:4071
```

...  and so on.

Obviously I cannot do this sorting manually it will take me forever.  Any solution will be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: rough guess: create a new column ('B') beside these values (col 'A'), and have a formula to substract the current col A value from col A row -1, e.g. `=A7-A6`. That'll give you the difference in the values. If the diff is 1, it can be collapse and you can try grouping on that.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply.  I worked on that idea but I am still doing lots of manual manipulation of the data during the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're looking for but it shows a method.

Formula + pivot.
[image]

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the input.  I will play with that formula and see how it works out.

Comment: How did you create that report on the right?  You deleted the in range values and left the Min, Max and self range values.

Comment: created a pivot table and hid the in range values displaying only min range, max range and selfrange. (pivot) (Column label 0)  the column values was "Results" value became the 0 column label.

Comment: That pivot table function goes beyond my capabilities, but the Max, Min equation is excellent.  I can generate a condensed report of my ranges much faster with it!!!  FYI, the numbers represent mining claims that were recorded at various times over various sectors.  Instead of printing out all of the ~2500 claim numbers, printing out the ranges makes more sense.

Comment: I should note, it only works if the values are ordered and there are no duplicates.